# Iterator that pop's a list property in next() and recharges itself?

Tags: python, iterator

I am building an iterator class that gets it's values from a paginated search results page. Something like this:

```
class resultsIterator:
    def __init__(self, results, page=1):
        self.results = results
        self.page = page

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if len(self.results):
            return self.results.pop(0)
        else:
            # if results' page is less than expected, get new results
            if self.page < 10:
                # recharge self with new results
                self = self.search(self.page+1)
                return self.next()
            return StopIteration
        pass

    @classmethod
    def search(cls, page=1):
        # at this point i should be scraping off search results
        # from a page and putting them on a list, but
        # to make this simpler, here's a generator instead
        results = [x*page for x in range(10)]
        return cls(results, page)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? What actually happens?

Comment: @user2357112 infinite loop, iterator returns first element of page 2

Comment: Code review - `if len(self.results):` should just be `if self.results:`

Comment: @AaronHall thanks, missed that

Answer (score 0):

```
self = self.search(self.page+1)
```

merely changes the value of the local variable `self`. It does not change the instance which called the `next` method.

---

Instead, change the attributes of `self` in the `search` method:

```
def search(self, page=1):
    self.results = [x*page for x in range(10)]
    self.page = page
```

---

Instead of defining `next`, I think it might be simpler to define `__iter__` like this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    while self.results:
        item = self.results.pop()
        yield item
        if not self.results and self.page < 10:
            self.search(self.page+1)
```

Comment: what I really wanted is to do something like: `Users.search()` which will return an iterator of `User` instances, so `search` should be a class method

Comment: @yowmamasita: You need to split up the "do the search" part from the "return an iterator" part. The latter can be a classmethod (an alternative constructor), but combining it with the first part makes it difficult to go from one page to another. I suppose you could play `yield from` games in Python 3.3+, if you really needed to, but you're fighting against yourself.

Comment: @Blckknght yes, that's what I did. See Ads.search() https://github.com/yowmamasita/pysulit/blob/master/pysulit/api.py